# Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER (has extras) }: not found

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am trying to use C2DM in my app, but I am getting some errors

```
10-14 11:21:14.904: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER (has extras) }: not found
```

**My code:**

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
        registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
        registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "andylor03@gmail.com");
        startService(registrationIntent);
```

Can any one help me in this...

Happy Code...!

Comment: Did you declare required permissions in your manifest? http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue.
To develop and test on the Android Emulator, you need to download the Android 2.2 version of the Google APIs Add-On into your SDK using the Android SDK and AVD Manager. Specifically, you need to download the component named "Google APIs by Google Inc, Android API 8". Then, you need to set up an AVD that uses that system image.

originally posted [here](http://androidforums.com/application-development/116833-c2dm-android-2-2-emulator.html)

Comment: How to set AVD with the System Image you are taking about?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I solved it:
you have just to register you Google Account (the one you have registered for C2DM) on your phone (or emulator), through the Setting Panel.
Of course, you must have installed the Android Market on the emulator too..

Comment: So when I deliver the app to customers I've to tell them log in via my Google Account, c'mon....

Comment: @yoshi I think they should have any one gmail account set-up on their phone.

Comment: I have 4.0.3 Anroid phone but I am using C2DM without any Google account registration in the device.

Comment: one thing i had to do also after loging the google account, is to restart the emulater

Comment: The Google account don't need to be the one you have created the project on api console